# BigQueryToPostgresOperator - provide project id

Tags: airflow

I am trying to query a view in a different gcp `project_id` than the one where composer/airflow is deployed and insert the content in a `cloudsql/postgres` instance using `BigQueryToPostgresOperator`.

How can I pass the project_id to the operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `gcp_conn_id` parameter.

The [BigQueryToPostgresOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_postgres.html) is extending the [BigQueryToSqlOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_sql/index.html) and it is using the `gcp_conn_id` for the GCP connection, including the project id.

But, make sure that you already created the `gcp_conn_id` in the Airflow connection before using it in your DAG. Read [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp.html) on how to create the connection.

Comment: I need to connect to a clousql instance with a private ip. Can i use somehow the cloudsql proxy from google?

Comment: I never tried it. But here is the documentation that might help -> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/connections/gcp_sql.html.